# submit via GET an email address avoiding url encoding?

Tags: email, forms

I might have a freudian lips but i cant figure out how to send an email address to a specific url without the url encodes the AT symbol in %40...
basically i have a basic form

```
<form class="firstLoginform" id="firstLoginform"  name="firstLoginform"  method="get" action="https://myurl" >

<label for="email" >Email Address</label>
<input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail"  size="20" maxlength="150">

<center>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</center>
</form>
```

but i submit the form the url is gonna be like

```
https://myurl?userEmail=myemail%40mydomain.com
```

but I NEED, for soe reason of the previous settings a ul like this

```
https://myurl?userEmail=myemail@mydomain.com
```

i dont have access to the page that is receiving the variables...so i wonder if i can send the email address AS IS..

thanks!!!

Comment: sorry, but is not really clear what a user is supposed to do other than asking and browsing answers.. you should have a reminder/alert mesg for that

Comment: asking and answering questions is really all a user is suppose to do. You'll need to mark it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark, like you've done on this question. You can review your history and go through your old questions and accept answers.

Comment: It's okay not to mark answers as accepted if no answer hasn't really helped you out, or if the question is new and you want to wait and see what other answers come up, but for older question you should go through and mark answers as accepted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't according to RFC1738, the URL Spec. The `@` symbol is reserved because it has a special meaning.

Answer (score 5):

As Alan mentioned the [URL specification (RFC1738)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) forbids the use of the @ symbol in URLs because it's reserved for use within any type of URL. An example of this would be an FTP URL which provides the option to specify a `username@host.domain` syntax.

Section 3 of the RFC shows a number of cases that use the @ symbol in a URL.

For this reason @ along with a number of other characters can't be used as part of an HTTP URL.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Variables in query strings must be encoded, otherwise it isn't a valid URL.